# Cut Video Clips Per Transcription Line

Tags: video, video-editor

I have hundreds of high quality films with transcriptions that need to be cut into short video clips per transcription line.

So I need one video clip per one transcription line.

Example:

- video_clip_home_0023.mp4
- video_clip_home_0023.srt

It would be even better to also have an image thumbnail for each clip.

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: "best" is not a useful phrase - it will depend on what tools you have at your disposal. What editing tools do you have?